# How will we confirm that the security of a particular page is secured or not? In the context of Web service testing

Tags: security, testing

I am testing a web service package and asked to confirm the security of a particular page is secured. 
I have no clue of how to do this. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Security is mainly used to protect an application against unforeseen actions that cause it to stop functioning or being exploited. Unforeseen actions can be either intentional or unintentional.

Security Testing ensures, that system and applications in an organization, are free from any loopholes that may cause a big loss. Security testing of any system is about finding all possible

Sample cases ensured while security testing

- Password should be in encrypted format
- Application or System should not allow invalid users
- Check cookies and session time for application
- For financial sites, Browser back button should not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no idea how to test for security, you shouldn't be testing for security. The most common web-based attacks (as per OWASP top 10 - http://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/scan-website-owasp-top-10-risks/?gclid=CjwKEAjw0-epBRDOp7f7lOG0zl4SJABxJg9qZSsVOyPay4K998pqVoqPnrdO8MtqXJq2ufPllT1M2xoCXqbw_wcB) tend to be lack of input validation, and authorization bypassing.

You'll want to test to see if you can save javascript, well-formed or otherwise. You'll want to test for possible SQL injections (ie: setting a username to "user' OR 1#'").

In short though; security is a vast field, and if you're working for a company that needs secure code, they should pay for training or hire someone who can properly test their code.

If this is for a personal project, use the OWASP top 10, and do a lot of research.